# how to reset remote master repository which is n commits ahead?

Tags: git

I want to rollback to a previous commit. So, i did `git reset --hard sha1` in the local repository and when i push it to remote master repository it gives me this

```
 git push docs master
 To https://github.com/sathya9897/docs.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sathya9897/docs.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
 behind
 hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
 hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

as it says my master is ahead of some commits but i want to rollback the master too to the current commit that i have on my local repository.
How can i reset the remote master repository to a previous commit?

Comment: You should never change public history. That means that you should not delete commits from your public github repository. You can revert these commits by using `git-revert` (see [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))

Comment: You can add `--force` to git push but that will obliterate the history from the point where you've modified it. Even stuff that others have put in. Make sure you understand the consequences of this before doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force this push: `git push docs +master`. You should consider possible users of your repo though and whether they can cope with upstream revisions disappearing, which is what musicmatze was probably referring to. Sometimes, publishing something comes with certain implicit guarantees that might be broken by doing this.